# How to set up ssl for my elasticsearch?

Tags: ssl, elasticsearch, ssl-certificate

I want to set ssl for elasticsearch.I had ssl keys but how to set ssl.Is it possible to set in elasticsearch.yml?

```
https://localhost:9200
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your options are either to pay for [Shield](https://www.elastic.co/products/shield) or set up a HTTP(S) reverse proxy such as [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) and [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/). But actually I don't have much first-hand expericen on Shield :/